# Azure .NET MVC Core Application: A suitable constructor for Model type could not be located

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to use a model I created (`RoleAssignmentRecord`) in my **Index.cshtml** file (in the `Pages` folder). Below is my Index.cshtml code:

```
@page
@using AccessChangeMonitoringUI.Models
@model RoleAssignmentRecord

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">OneAuthZ Change Monitoring</h1>
    <p>View OneAuthZ role change history and acknowledge role changes.</p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("RoleAssignmentController", "TestForm", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <label>Test Form</label>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    }
</div>
```

Below is my `RoleAssignmentRecord` code in the `Models` folder:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AccessChangeMonitoringUI.Models
{
    public class RoleAssignmentRecord
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        string id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "RoleAssignmentId")]
        string roleId { get; set; }
        List<RoleAssignmentChange> changeHistory { get; set; }
        RoleAssignment currentRow { get; set; }

        RoleAssignmentRecord(RoleAssignment currentRow, List<RoleAssignmentChange> changeHistory)
        {
            this.id = currentRow.Id;
            this.roleId = currentRow.Id;
            this.currentRow = currentRow;
            this.changeHistory = changeHistory;
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I run my application, I receive the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type
> 'AccessChangeMonitoringUI.Models.RoleAssignmentRecord' could not be
> located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for
> all parameters of a public constructor.

This seems strange, considering that I do have a constructor for `RoleAssignmentRecord`

Comment: Your constructor is private. See the second paragraph, here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/private-constructors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note that if you do not use an access modifier with the constructor [it will still be private by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/private-constructors).** However, the private modifier is usually used explicitly to make it clear that the class cannot be instantiated.

It should be **public** otherwise the DI cannot access it:

```
public RoleAssignmentRecord(RoleAssignment currentRow, List<RoleAssignmentChange> changeHistory)
{
    this.id = currentRow.Id;
    this.roleId = currentRow.Id;
    this.currentRow = currentRow;
    this.changeHistory = changeHistory;
}
```